# php my_sql connection problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem trying to connect to a my_sql database.  I'm very new to PHP, so this is probably a very simple problem.  At the top of my index.php I have the following code:

```
try
   {
      echo 'here 1';
      $db=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
      echo 'here 2';
      if(!$db)
      {
         echo 'here 3';
      }
         $db_selected=mysql_select_db("alphaes", $db);
      echo 'here 4';

      if (!$db_selected) {
         die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
      }
      echo 'here 5';
   }
   catch (Exception $e)
   {
      echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }
```

The problem is that the only output from the page is 'here 1'.  If I comment out all the database code the page loads ok.  There's something wrong with the connect code, however I don't see the mysql_error or exception written to the browser.  Do these get logged to a file somewhere?  Can anyone see a problem with the code?

The username and password are correct.

Any help is much appreciated,

Mark

Comment: exception will never be raised, as mysql driver don't support them, but for the rest it's strange. I'd suggest to change that stupid die() to something more intelligent. if (!$db) throw something for example

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` --- put this in the beginning of your script

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I bet he just has mysql extention not plugged in.

Comment: whoops! good catch! However to replace die() with throw still would be definitely good

Comment: Do you really need to use try/catch? If not, as you are new to PHP I'd suggest following some of the more simple code as it is here http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who replied - turns out that it was very 'beginners' error - mysql was not enabled in the php configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

here's a very simple example that uses the newer mysqli extension in conjunction with exception handling:

```
<?php

ob_start(); 

try
{
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "foo_dbo", "pass", "foo_db", 3306);

    if ($db->connect_errno) 
        throw new exception(sprintf("Could not connect: %s", $db->connect_error));

    $sqlCmd = "select * from users order by username";
    $result = $db->query($sqlCmd);

    if(!$result) throw new exception(sprintf("Invalid query : %s", $sqlCmd));

    if($db->affected_rows <= 0){
        echo "no users found !";
    }
    else{
        $users = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        foreach($users as $u) echo $u["username"], "<br/>";
    }
    $result->close();
}
catch(exception $ex)
{
    ob_clean(); 
    echo sprintf("zomg borked - %s", $ex->getMessage());
}

if(!$db->connect_errno) $db->close();
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If it only outputs "here 1" that means the code stops at:

`$db=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die(mysql_error());`

I think it is because `mysql_error` needs to get the last connection from mysql_connect, and the connection fails.

From the docs:

The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. **If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments**. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

(emphasis mine)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Try changing `mysql_error` with some string output and see if it works. If it works, then the error is in the database connection.

Answer (score -1):

Try without a password: `$db=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());`